# Not able to delete particular registry in regedit using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, registry

I happened to write a registry programming using C#

```
const string basereg="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\ram";
Registry.SetValue(basereg,"r","s",RegistryValueKind.String);
```

- which creates a value string "r" inside ram subkey.

after adding below code i expected code delete key named "r" inside ram[mentioned above subkey] but i am gettin expection as "System.NullReferenceException"

```
string pat = "\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\ram";
RegistryKey del = null;
del = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(pat, true);
del.DeleteValue("r");
```

Thanks

Regards,
Ram

Comment: I wonder if OpenSubKey() is returning null even though that seems odd.

Answer (score 0):

Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey() rtries to open a key, but `ram` is a value, not a key.

Try this:

```
string pat = "\\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node";
```

Registry terms 'key' and 'value' are not the typical usage.  Key's have multiple values with different names each, in the registry.